# html problem in a .jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am having a problem.

this is the code:

```
List<QueryDescription> queries = null;
                        Config f = new Config();
                        queries = f.getQList();
                        out.println(queries.size());

                        out.println("<table border=\"1\">");
                        out.println("<tr><td><b>Select One</b></td>");
                        out.println("<td><b></b>#</td>");
                        out.println("<td><b>Name</b></td>");
                        out.println("<td><b>Description</b></td></tr>");

                        for (QueryDescription qd: queries) {

                            out.print("<tr><td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"rButton\" value=\"" + qd.getId() + "\"></td>");
                            out.print("<td>" + qd.getId() + "</td>");
                            out.print("<td>" + qd.getName() + "</td>");
                            out.print("<td>" + qd.getDescription() + "</td>");
                            out.print("</tr>");

                        }
```

I am trying to print out in the table:
1st column: radio button
2nd column: id
3rd column: name
4th column: description

any help would be great!

thanks,

SORRY GUYS. THE PROBLEM IS THAT IT IS PRINTING OUT EVERY OBJECT IN EVERY TD EXCEPT THE FIRST RADIO BUTTON COLUMN... WEIRD

Comment: Are you trying to print out for debugging purposes? Why not use a debugger for that?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what the problem is, you need to close your table tag.

```
out.print("</table>")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem but the missing `<table>` closing tag:

```
    out.println("</table>");
```

Also, check the encoding of your `out` object, and don't forget to `close/flush` the stream